# unselect row in wpf datagrid

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, binding, wpfdatagrid, double-click

I have

```
<DataGrid Name="grid" MouseDoubleClick="Attributes_MouseDoubleClick" >
```

I need to **unselect a row** whenever a click event occurs anywhere else other than the Datagrid row.

i.e. `grid.CurrentItem` should be `null`

I need to fire a double-click event **only** on a row.
But, the problem is, once I select a row and double-click elsewhere on the grid(header, empty scrollviewer area, etc) the double-click event fires as expected but the CurrentItem is sometimes the selected row and sometimes null.

To prevent this behaviour.. I need to unselect the selected row.

Any ideas as to how I should approach this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can search the Visual Tree of the event source for an instance of type DataGridRow to determine if you double clicked on a row or somewhere else.

The following site [Detecting Double Click Events on the WPF DataGrid](http://www.hardcodet.net/2009/03/detecting-double-click-events-on-the-wpf-datagrid) contains good example.
I've include the code here in case the site is no longer available.

Here is the event handler for double click:

```
private void DataGridRow_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
  //search the object hierarchy for a datagrid row
  DependencyObject source = (DependencyObject)e.OriginalSource;
  var row = DataGridTextBox.Helpers.UIHelpers.TryFindParent<DataGridRow>(source);

  //the user did not click on a row
  if (row == null) return;

  //[insert great code here...]

  e.Handled = true;
}
```

Here is the code to help search the Visual Tree:

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Media;

namespace DataGridTextBox.Helpers
{
  public static class UIHelpers
  {
    public static T TryFindParent<T>(this DependencyObject child) where T : DependencyObject
    {
      //get parent item
      DependencyObject parentObject = GetParentObject(child);

      //we've reached the end of the tree
      if (parentObject == null) return null;

      //check if the parent matches the type we're looking for
      T parent = parentObject as T;
      if (parent != null)
      {
        return parent;
      }
      else
      {
        //use recursion to proceed with next level
        return TryFindParent<T>(parentObject);
      }
    }

    public static DependencyObject GetParentObject(this DependencyObject child)
    {
      if (child == null) return null;

      //handle content elements separately
      ContentElement contentElement = child as ContentElement;
      if (contentElement != null)
      {
        DependencyObject parent = ContentOperations.GetParent(contentElement);
        if (parent != null) return parent;

        FrameworkContentElement fce = contentElement as FrameworkContentElement;
        return fce != null ? fce.Parent : null;
      }

      //also try searching for parent in framework elements (such as DockPanel, etc)
      FrameworkElement frameworkElement = child as FrameworkElement;
      if (frameworkElement != null)
      {
        DependencyObject parent = frameworkElement.Parent;
        if (parent != null) return parent;
      }

      //if it's not a ContentElement/FrameworkElement, rely on VisualTreeHelper
      return VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(child);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That event is fired by the grid, not by the row. I mean, is fired when you double-click somewhere in the grid, it could be a row selected or not (or not the row that you spect wich is worse).

You could edit the itemtemplate for each row and include there your double-click event or [capture](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/c28355ce-23d4-4025-b19d-d7771228af63) the cordenates from the mouse, but this is a little bit tricky.

Hope helps!

Comment: "capture the cordenates"?..  Seriously?

Comment: I'm afraid, i'm serious. http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/c28355ce-23d4-4025-b19d-d7771228af63

Comment: Well.. How about this approach.. http://techiethings.blogspot.com/2010/05/get-wpf-datagrid-row-and-cell.html

Comment: Sorry, I agree that is quite possible, but simply not viable for me, Thanks anyway..