# Toggle Selected Row in WPF DataGrid

Tags: wpf, datagrid

I want to be able to toggle selection when a row is clicked. So, first click should highlight it and second click (again on the row) should unhighlight it (and fire an event). Is it even possible? I'm using a OnSelectionChanged event but that gets fired only when I click on a different row than the selected one.

Comment: You might be able to use the `Click` event and check the selected index to see if it's the selected row that's been clicked. Not sure what you can do after that though....

Comment: I tried with 'Click' already. It is way to complicated. Also, it won't work in certain circumstances like if you click anything outside a row, the Click gets fired. Either I've to do a hittesting or something more non-trivial.
I think I got an alternative solution that works. Although looks like a bit hacky but I can bear it rather than the ugly click. Will post a solution once I'm convinced that it works as expected. Thanks though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there a some useful answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4815436/unselect-row-in-wpf-datagrid)(searching the visual tree) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6465178/how-can-i-get-a-datagrid-to-unselect-on-click-when-selectionmode-extended)(check in PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown).