# WPF Grid and focus of controls inside it

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

I have *MyContainer* User Control with Grid inside. Each cell of this Grid contains a some control derived from *MyControlBase* class. These controls are added dynamically.

I need to implement a *FocusedControl* bound property in *MyContainer* to get currently focused or set focus to any of *MyControlBase* children. I know about *FocusManager.FocusedElement* but haven't ideas how to implement it properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I found how to do it myself.

First define our new dependence property `FocusedAdapterProperty` as usual:

```
    public static readonly DependencyProperty FocusedAdapterProperty;

    static SpreadGridControl()
    {
        FocusedAdapterProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("FocusedAdapter",
                            typeof(object), typeof(SpreadGridControl),
                            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null, null));
    }

    public object FocusedAdapter
    {
        get { return GetValue(FocusedAdapterProperty); }
        set { SetValue(FocusedAdapterProperty, value); }
    }
```

Next add GotFocus handler to parent container e.g. `<Grid GotFocus="Grid_OnGotFocus">`
Check the *e.OriginalSource* and search most common ancestor of required type and set property to new value:

```
    private void Grid_OnGotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var control = UIHelpers.TryFindParent<ControlBase>
            ((DependencyObject)e.OriginalSource);
        if (control != null)
            FocusedAdapter = control.Adapter;
    }
```

The implementation of *TryFindParent* can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4815436/unselect-row-in-wpf-datagrid)

Answer (score 0):

Dunno if this helps your situation, or if it's even the right way to go about mine, but in a pinch I've found that listening for the Loaded event on the object I want to focus and then using  Dispatcher.BeginInvoke to send a Focus request to my control on the Background or ApplicationIdle priority has worked when other methods haven't. For example:

```
private void MyControlLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.ApplicationIdle, new Action( () => MyControl.Focus() ));
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I know how to make any element focused :) I need a pretty set/get property to control it dynamically to binding in other controls.